# Proving $(A \cup B) -C = (A-C) \cup (B-C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Proving $(A \cup B) -C = (A-C) \cup (B-C)$

I did it as follows, but I'm not sure about the method. Let me know if there is a fault.

Let $x \in (A \cup B) -C $
$$ x \in (A \cup B) \land x \notin C \\
(x \in A \lor x \in B) \land x \notin C\\
(x \in A \land x \notin C) \lor ( x \in B\land x \notin C) \\
x \in (A-C) \lor x \in (B-C) \\
x \in (A-C) \cup (B-C) \\
\therefore (A \cup B) -C \subseteq (A-C) \cup (B-C) ----1 $$

Then Let $y \in (A-C) \cup (B-C)$
$$ y \in (A-C) \lor y \in (B-C) \\ 
(y \in A \land y \notin C) \lor ( y \in B\land y \notin C) \\
(y \in A \lor y \in B) \land y \notin C\\
y \in (A \cup B) \land y \notin C \\
y \in (A \cup B) -C \\
\therefore (A-C) \cup (B-C) \subseteq   (A \cup B) -C  ----2 $$

By 1 and 2 the required identity is proved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good to me, but could be done simpler. Every step in your proof of $(A\cup B)-C\subseteq (A-C)\cup (B-C)$ is actually reversible, so you can say that that is already a proof of equality.

Even simpler, you don't even have to take $x$ from the set, since you know that for any three sets $X,Y$:

- $(X\cup Y)\cap Z = (X\cap Z)\cup(Y\cap Z)$
- $X-Y=X\cap Y^c$

Using only these two rules, you quickly get:

$$(A\cup B)-C = (A\cup B)\cap C^c = (A\cap C^c)\cup (B\cap C^c) = (A-C)\cup (B-C)$$