# How to prove that $(A \cup B) - C = (A - C) \cap (B - C)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

If true, prove else provide a counter example. This is a homework question and I cant figure it out. Please help.

Comment: The assertion is incorrect. It should be $(A - C) \cup (B - C)$

Comment: Is it right that this question has "discrete-mathematics" tag?

Comment: Is it a typo? It should be union.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884398/proving-a-cup-b-c-a-c-cup-b-c

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What if $A=\{a\}$, $B=\{b\}$, and $C=\emptyset$?

Comment: Thank you. The counter example works.